# How to convert nvarchar to varbinary accurately

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has column `[password]` stored as `nvarchar(max)`. I want to convert it into `varbinary(max)`.

I created a new column called `[temp]` and declared it as `varbinary(max)`. Then I updated using `CONVERT`:

```
update tempuser set [temp]=CONVERT(varbinary(max), CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[password]))
```

Now in the [temp] column the value is different. For example, one value for `[password]` started with this:

```
0x3E6AFF88...
```

The corresponding entry in [temp] starts with:

```
0x30783345...
```

Also when `[password]` is `NULL`, `[temp]` becomes `0x4E554C4C`.

Comment: Why do you suppose they should be the same?

Comment: Agreed with @Goat. You're converting a string that happens to *look* like a binary value because it starts with 0x. Unfortunately these are not the same thing. Try `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [password]), 1)`.

Answer (score 13):

You're converting a string that happens to look like a binary value because it starts with `0x`. Unfortunately these are not the same thing, and in order for SQL Server to understand that you want to interpret the string as an actual binary value to convert directly, instead of a string to convert to its binary representation, you need to use a style parameter:

```
UPDATE dbo.tempuser -- please always use the schema prefix
  SET [temp] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [password], 1); -- and semi-colons
```

*Note that converting an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is unnecessary.*

Now, it is possible that because you chose `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for some reason, that the column contains garbage that *can't* be converted, so you may encounter this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.

In that case, you'll need to find the values that don't start with `0x` (or otherwise contain ineligible characters) and fix them.

Comment: Is there no way to, say copy the whole date as it is into a column of data type varbinary?

Comment: @user2429070 I don't know what you mean. That's what the update does, but the original values have to be able to be converted to a binary. Since you stored "binary" values in a string column, there's no guarantee they can all be converted to binary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your password field isn't actually a varbinary, despite looking like one.

Run these for an example:

```
SELECT CAST('0x3E6AFF88BEB29D9B234B9E5A5AD329D8D3F33200EC4EE02749C56AD58D040976' AS varbinary(max))
SELECT CAST(CAST('0x3E6AFF88BEB29D9B234B9E5A5AD329D8D3F33200EC4EE02749C56AD58D040976' AS varbinary(max))AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT CAST('dog' AS VARBINARY(MAX))
SELECT CAST(CAST('dog' AS VARBINARY(max))AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

You see that your result is the equivalent of your initial string, just in varbinary format.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Try this: `SELECT CAST(123456 AS VARBINARY(MAX));`, you'll see that the result is `0x0001E240` which has an `E` in there. `VARBINARY` can use letters from `A` till `F`

Comment: Huh, interesting, thanks for that. Even my 'dog' example had a letter that I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Just as [Hart Co's answer shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17555229/2806424), use the following code to convert passwords to hex numbers.

```
UPDATE dbo.tempuser SET [temp] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [password], 1);
```

If you got

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5
> Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.

That means your have one or multiple password contains are a valid hex string. One of reason that is easy to ignore is you have odd number of characters. You can use the following code to check which row causing the error:

```
SELECT id, TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [password], 1) AS try_convert
FROM tempuser
WHERE try_convert IS NULL
```

Instead of return an error, [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will return NULL if it find something cannot be converted.

If you got rows contains odd number of characters, you can use [RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to left padding zeros to let them valid.

```
CONVERT(
    varbinary(MAX),
    RIGHT('000000000000'+SUBSTRING([password], 3, LEN([reg_address])), 16),
    2
)
```